# How to draw a rectangular which is moves by mouse click

Tags: java, processing

The task is as follows: a) draw a square that will change its size and colour depending on the movement of the mouse b) make it so that with each click of the mouse, a square is drawn with the same size and colour parameters from the location of the mouse and freezes in place c) do the previous operation but there should already be a few mouse clicks

I did part a and figured out part b a little

```
void setup(){

  size(500, 255);

}

int size = mouseX%100;


void draw(){ 

  int size = mouseX%100;
  background(50);
  fill(255 - mouseY, 125 - mouseY, 175 - mouseY);
  stroke(255);
  rectMode(CENTER);

  if ((mouseX >= 100) & (mouseX <= 199) | (mouseX >= 300) & (mouseX <= 399) | (mouseX >= 500) & (mouseX <= 599)  ) {

    size = 99;
    size = size - mouseX%100;

  } 

  rect(mouseX,mouseY,size,size);

  if (mousePressed) {

    int x = width - mouseX;
    int y = height - mouseY;
    rect(-x,-y,size,size);

  }



}
```

I expect that for every click, that I did, I will see squares in the window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with keypressed when drawing a square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821923/problem-with-keypressed-when-drawing-a-square)

Comment: Is the update don't related to dictionaries?

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your code](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging)? Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected?

Comment: I think that is something not right in this part of the code : if (mousePressed) {

    int x = width - mouseX;
    int y = height - mouseY;
    rect(-x,-y,size,size);

Comment: @KuzmaPlugachev *"Is the update don't related to dictionaries?"* - sorry, but I've no idea what you mean. There is not any dictionary.